# Brewing stand not accepting water bottles

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I've built the automatic brewing station from [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k5CzlBmmbuc). I've been through it three times to make sure I have everything as per the video, but things aren't quite working.

The full water bottles make it to the hopper than is pointing towards the brewing stand but for some reason they won't load into the brewing stand. I have a feeling it's something 'locking' the brewing stand (like you can lock hoppers), but that's just a guess. Here's a screen cap of the offending hopper;

[image]

The hopper is meant to be locked while the stand empties of the previous batch, but for some reason it never refills.

If it matters I'm on 1.11.2 and I'm playing on a server.

Comment: Does [MC-111753](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-111753) describe your issue?

Answer (score 1):

I do believe that the water bottle should be inserted from the top, as I do think that only the blaze powder can be added from the side (that was added before 1.11) hopefully this helps...

Answer (score 0):

There maybe multiple issues here:

1. Sometimes servers have specific glitch "fixes" that hinder you to be able to do certain things. For example, there is a glitch in Minecraft that uses redstone. When used, it acts as a X-ray machine allowing the player to see underground. Many servers prevent this from occurring and the result is some redstone contraptions don't work properly.
2. A redstone pulse or current will stop hoppers from pulling things into them and from going out of them. Make sure no other redstone current is interfering with your hoppers. You may have to space things better.
3. Make sure the tutorial you watched corresponds with the version of Minecraft you are running. For example, I use Minecraft commands all the time and it seems every time Minecraft updates, the way commands are written get changed and no longer apply. Make sure the video still applies.
4. Some servers allow multiple versions of Minecraft players all at once. This can influence your game play. For example, If you play with 1.8 players, and your contraption is for a fairly new version (1.10 or 1.11) than it also may not work because the server has to compromise features so all players (of different versions) can still play without the server crashing.